# How to pass data from SQL Server through class library in mvc and show it to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a SQL Server database with a table which is connected with a class library with a `.DBML` Linq-to-SQL model, and I have to pass data from SQL Server through class library to ASP.NET MVC - how do I do that?

```
public static Kontakt ViewContakt(int ID)
{
    ContactManagerDBDataContext con = new ContactManagerDBDataContext();

    var linq = (from cont in con.Contacts where cont.ContactID == ID select cont).First();

    Kontakt kontakt = new Kontakt();
    kontakt.FirstName = linq.FirstName;
    kontakt.LastName = linq.LastName;
    kontakt.Address = linq.Address;
    kontakt.ContactTypeID = linq.ContactTypeID;
    kontakt.ContactID = linq.ContactID;
    kontakt.InsertDate = linq.InsertDate;

    return kontakt;
}
```

This is my function where I create linq query and I mapped contacts from SQL Server to `Kontakt` from the class library.

```
public static KontaktModel View( int ID)
{
    Kontakt kontakt = new Kontakt();
    KontaktModel kontaktModel = new KontaktModel();

    kontaktModel.Address = kontakt.Address;
    kontaktModel.ContactID = kontakt.ContactID;
    kontaktModel.ContactTypeID = kontakt.ContactTypeID;
    kontaktModel.FirstName = kontakt.FirstName;
    kontaktModel.InsertDate = kontakt.InsertDate;
    kontaktModel.LastName = kontakt.LastName;

    Class1.ViewContakt(ID);

    return kontaktModel;
}
```

Then I do same in ASP.NET MVC, trying to map `Kontakt` from class library to `KontaktModel` in ASP.NET MVC.

Then I try to pass that function to a controller, and pass that function to a view, ID from View.

```
public ActionResult View(int ID)
{
    return View(Functions.View(ID));
}
```

[All contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT1Oz.png)

`Index` code for view is:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("View", "View", new { ID = m.ContactID })%>
```

[Result when I click View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qkRO.png)

And here my html in a View:

```
Contact ID <%= Model.ContactID.ToString()%><br />
Contact Type ID <%= Model.ContactTypeID.ToString()%><br />
First Name <%= Model.FirstName%><br />
Last Name <%= Model.LastName%><br />
Address <%= Model.Address %><br />
Insert Date <%= Model.InsertDate %><br />
```

My view html is strongly type and he use `Model.KontaktModel` class.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In method

```
public static KontaktModel View( int ID)
```

you passing data from newly created object,
instead needs to first fetch data from method as

```
Kontakt kontakt = Class1.ViewContakt(ID);
```

then it will work.